# I got this "warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)" for several lines in the code

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to fix this warning? The code cannot continue compile because of this warning. Please please give me some suggestions! Thank you so much!   I copied four parts of the code where
the warning points to.

```
 template <typename T>
std::vector<StructNodeElem<T> *> *_groupStructOfString(const char *data) throw(const char *){
  std::istringstream is(data);
  std::vector<StructNodeElem<T> *> *gstruct = new std::vector<StructNodeElem<T> *>;


template <typename T>
std::vector<StructNodeElem<T> *> *_readGroupStruct(const char *file) throw(const char *){
  std::ifstream infile;
  infile.open (file, ifstream::in);
  if(! infile.good())
    throw("readGroupStruct: cannot open file");


template <typename T>
std::vector<StructNodeElem<T> *> *_simpleGroupTree(int *degr, int n) throw(const char *){
  std::vector<int> degrees;
  for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    degrees.push_back(degr[i]);




template <typename T>
Vector<T> *_graphOfGroupStruct(std::vector<StructNodeElem<T> *> *gstruct,SpMatrix<bool> **pgroups,SpMatrix<bool> **pgroups_var) throw(const char *) {
  int nb_vars;
  Vector<T> *peta_g;
  if (! checkGroupTree<T>(gstruct,false,&nb_vars))
    throw("graphOfGroupStruct: bad input data");




template <typename T>
int _treeOfGroupStruct(std::vector<StructNodeElem<T> *> *gstruct,int **pperm,int *pnb_vars,Vector<T> **peta_g,SpMatrix<bool> **pgroups,Vector<int> **pown_variables,Vector<int> **pN_own_variables) throw(const char *){
  int nb_vars;
  *pnb_vars = 0;
  if (! checkGroupTree<T>(gstruct,true,&nb_vars))
    throw("treeOfGroupStruct: bad input data");
```

Comment: Use `noexcept` to instead indicate that a function does not throw, but I can't remember which version of MSVC, if any, supports that.

Comment: Just do not use exception specifications besides throw() or noexcept (C++11) - please search the web for reasons

Comment: Also: Please throw an exception derived from std::exception, unless it's a really bad one (like std::bad_alloc).

Comment: @chris These functions are actually throwing, how would noexept help?

Comment: @imreal, It wouldn't here, but `noexcept` is better than `throw()` in general, and the general advice is not to have `throw(something)` at all. This is similar to `noexcept(false)`, which it would have by default.

Comment: @chris agree on that.

Answer (score 2):

Check the msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa28fef8.aspx.

Summary, just use the pragma `#pragma warning( disable : 4290 )`

Comment: Are you sure this is better advice considering the OP doesn't know why it happens/what it wants in order to not give the warning?

Comment: @chris The problem is in the function declarations, Visual C++ just ignores the specification. It seems like the OP didn't write the code (and it might be working code except for the warnings) so it is better to just leave the specifications there.